# Date Functions Trunc (SysDate)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running the below query to get data recorded in the past 24 hours. I need the same data recorded starting midnight (DATE > 12:00 AM) and also data recorded starting beginning of the month. Not sure if using between will work or if there is better option. Any suggestions.

```
SELECT COUNT(NUM)
FROM TABLE
WHERE
STATUS = 'CNLD'
AND
TRUNC(TO_DATE('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + OPEN_DATE/86400) = trunc(sysdate)
```

Output (Just need Count). OPEN_DATE Data Type is NUMBER. the output below displays count in last 24 hours. I need the count beginning midnight and another count starting beginning of the month.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data and expected output, and your actual column name (it can't be called `DATE`) and its data type (which seems to be `NUMBER` not `DATE`, representing some number of seconds since 1970-01-01 - so an 'epoch date'). The version you've shown should give you data since midnight, not the last 24 hours, so your question is a bit confusing and I'm not sure what you are really asking.

Comment: I have updated the post with the information.

Comment: Storing values as the number of seconds past 1970 is typically done using the UTC time zone. You may get incorrect values if `SYSDATE` is not also in the UTC time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you've shown will get the count of rows where `OPEN_DATE` is an 'epoch date' number representing time after midnight this morning*. The condition:

```
TRUNC(TO_DATE('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + OPEN_DATE/86400) = trunc(sysdate)
```

requires every `OPEN_DATE` value in your table (or at least all those for CNLD rows) to be converted from a number to an actual date, which is going to be doing a lot more work than necessary, and would stop a standard index against that column being used. It could be rewritten as:

```
OPEN_DATE >= (trunc(sysdate) - date '1970-01-01') * 86400
```

which converts midnight this morning to its epoch equivalent, once, and compares all the numbers against that value; using an index if there is one and the optimiser thinks it's appropriate.

To get everything since the start of the month you could just change the default behaviour of `trunc()`, which is to truncate to the 'DD' element, to truncate to the start of the month instead:

```
OPEN_DATE >= (trunc(sysdate, 'MM') - date '1970-01-01') * 86400
```

And the the last 24 hours, subtract a day from the current time instead of truncating it:

```
OPEN_DATE >= ((sysdate - 1) - date '1970-01-01') * 86400
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5dec08a145d185de553d0b337ebcc7a7) with some made-up data to get 72 back for today, more for the last 24 hours, and more still for the whole month.

Based on your current query I'm assuming there won't be any future-dated values, so you don't need to worry about an upper bound for any of these.

<sub>*Ignoring leap seconds...</sub>

Comment: Thank you Alex, worked like a charm.

Comment: Note: Epoch time is usually measured from 1970-01-01T00:00:00 UTC. If `SYSDATE` is not in the UTC time zone and you are following that convention then you need to convert it to UTC else the range will be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a column that is of data type TIMESTAMP and you only want to select rows where that TIMESTAMP indicates that it is today's date? And as a related problem, you want to find those that are the current month, based on some system values like CURRENT TIMESTAMP and CURRENT DATE? If so, let's call your column TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP instead of (reserved word) DATE. Your first query could be:

```
SELECT COUNT(NUM)
FROM TABLE
WHERE
STATUS = 'CLND'
AND
DATE(TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP)=CURRENT DATE
```

The second example of finding all for the current month up to today's date could be:

```
SELECT COUNT(NUM)
FROM TABLE
WHERE
STATUS = 'CLND'
AND
YEAR(DATE(TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP)=YEAR(CURRENT DATE) AND
MONTH(DATE(TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP)=MONTH(CURRENT DATE) AND
DAY(DATE(TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP)<=DAY(CURRENT DATE)
```

Comment: It is not Data Type TimeStamp, but number.

Comment: This is also using syntax that isn't valid for Oracle; and seems to assume date's don't have time components.